# HtmlEasy and Silken to serve mobile specific page

Tags: mobile, google-closure-templates

I'm busy building a web page where I'm using HtmlEasy and Silken with Google Closure Templates.

With ASP.NET MVC4 there is a technique of serving a mobile version of a web page by changing the file name to *.mobile.*. So it is not just the same version served up using a different stylesheet - the contents/data too can be different. This is really great since not everything may be relevant for a person using a mobile device.

Does HtmlEasy and Silken provide the same or similar feature? I can't seem to find anything that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you need to detect any mobile device then its better to make use of a database.

For my own project I'm using [51Degrees](http://51degrees.mobi) Lite. Pass the user-agent to the lib and it'll tell you if the device is mobile or not. Then serve your soy template(s) accordingly.